# User specified ABEND code for Java Program on z/OS

Tags: java, java-native-interface, zos

If I set up an environment variable in JZOS launcher

> EXPORT JZOS_ABEND_EXIT=50

and then invoke `System.exit(51)` in Java code the program will be terminated like this:

> IEF450I MYPROG JAVAJVM CREATE - ABEND=S000 U3333 REASON=00000010

Is it possible to specify abend code, for example to make it U999 instead of U3333. I found a cryptic reference to LE abend routine 'CEE3ABD' in [How to trigger a user ABEND?](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/threadTopic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014248120), but would appreciate it if somebody could point out how to invoke this routine from Java. Do I need to write JNI code and invoke it from C language? Or there is an easier way to this?

Comment: It's been a very long time since I did anything on zos, but the [*response*](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014248120&permalinkReplyUuid=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014248146) on your link seems relevant. Also, shouldn't you be using `50` there? Basically, I *think* the suggestion is to use JCL (Job Control Language) to monitor the exit code and generate the appropriate ABEND code. If there is such a C library, you should be able to call it with JNI or JNA. But I think the batch solution from the link is probably easier.

Comment: And when I say a long time, "zos" was called OS/390 (and OS/400 on minis) at the time. [IBM Documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3SA231385/$file/ieab600_v2r3.pdf).... it's always so ***beautiful***.

Comment: Pages 292-293 are the part I think you want. But well, I can't tell if pages 4, 26 and 54 are intentionally blank. So they seem to have slipped some (at least compared to how I remember them). The answer is probably in the documentation somewhere. As for why it works like it does, they still have software from the 50s-70s running banks and social security and unemployment, etc. And that stuff had to run from punch cards (at the time). And IBM had to (usually) go and invent some way to do it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch 51 is correct - any value *greater* than `JZOS_ABEND_EXIT` will trigger the abend.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You might find the [Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4/en/homepage.html) version of the IBM documentation more friendly than the PDF.

Comment: @cschneid [Possibly](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/4869801). It's always reassuring when things are ***consistent***.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The URL that you provided to IBM Community Home
did not work for me. Should I join some group first? What would be the group name? Thank you.

Comment: @PavelGanelin What Community Home link? I gave a link to the JCL documentation (and cshneid helpfully linked to the knowledge center where you can read it in an easier form). I also found a bug fix site where they reported fixing the "this page intentionally left blank" bug I found. IBM will never change. Bless them. They're a rock. A rock of blue linebar paper.

Answer (score 3):

I played around a bit and found that for 31-bit JZOS you can also register a user-written condition-handler via the LE-runtime-options and use it to catch the U3333 abend and change it to something else.

Unfortunately it seems that (as of z/OS 2.3) there's no way to register a condition-handler via runtime-options in 64-bit LE.

In your JCL you can add the options via the CEEOPTS DD-statement:

```
//CEEOPTS  DD   *              
ENVAR("JZOS_ABEND_EXIT=50")    
USRHDLR(MYHDLR)                
/*
```

In the handler you can analyze the LE-condition.token for message CEE3250 (User-initiated abend). In this case you can call CEEGQDT to get the abend-specific q_data that contains the abend- and reason-code, so you can identify the U3333.

In case you want to issue a different ABEND you can then call CEE3ABD. Note that I only got it to work by calling CEE3ABD with `CLEANUP = 0` to disable any further LE condition handling. I guess otherwise something screws up because another condition is raised while the current handler has not yet exited.

Here's my example-hanlder written in PL/I, but it can also be done in COBOL or C (or Assembler if you prefer...)

```
MYHDLR: PROC(P1,P2,P3,P4) OPTIONS(BYVALUE FETCHABLE);                  

   DCL(P1,P2,P3,P4) POINTER;                                           
/* DCL CUR_COND     CHAR(12);  */  /*P1->*/                            
   DCL TOKEN        BIN FIXED(31) BASED(P2);                           
   DCL RESULT       BIN FIXED(31) BASED(P3);                           
/* DCL NEW_COND     CHAR(12);  */  /*P4->*/                            


   DCL COND_PTR      POINTER;                                          
   DCL 1 COND_STRU   BASED(COND_PTR),                                  
          2 SEVERITY BIN FIXED(15),                                    
          2 MESSAGE  BIN FIXED(15),                                    
          2 FLAGS    BIT(8),                                           
          2 FACILITY CHAR(3),                                          
          2 ISI      BIN FIXED(31);                                    

   DCL QDATA_PTR   POINTER;                                            

   DCL 1 QDATA        BASED(QDATA_PTR),                                
         2 QCOUNT_PTR POINTER,                                         
         2 ABCODE_PTR POINTER,                                         
         2 REASON_PTR POINTER;                                         

   DCL ABCODE         BIN FIXED(31) BASED(ABCODE_PTR);                 
   DCL REASON         BIN FIXED(31) BASED(REASON_PTR);                 

   DCL MYABCODE       BIN FIXED(31);                                   
   DCL CLEANUP        BIN FIXED(31);                                   

   DCL FEEDBACK     CHAR(12);                                          

   DCL SYSPRINT     FILE;                                              
   DCL (CEEGQDT,CEE3ABD)  ENTRY OPTIONS(ASM);                          

   PUT SKIP LIST('HANDLER CALLED');                                

   /* ANALYZE CONDITION */                                         
   COND_PTR = P1;                                                  
   PUT SKIP EDIT(FACILITY,MESSAGE,SEVERITY)(A,F(4),F(4));          
   IF FACILITY = 'CEE' & MESSAGE = 3250 THEN DO;                   
      PUT SKIP LIST('ABEND ISSUED');                               
      CALL CEEGQDT(COND_STRU,QDATA_PTR,FEEDBACK);                  
      COND_PTR = ADDR(FEEDBACK); /* REUSE TOKEN STRUCTURE */       
      PUT SKIP EDIT(SEVERITY,ABCODE)(F(6),F(6));                   
      IF SEVERITY = 0 &          /* CEEGQDT CALL SUCCESSFUL */     
         ABCODE = 3333           /* ONLY HANDLE USER-ABEND U3333 */
      THEN DO;                                                     
         CLEANUP = 0;            /* NO LE-CLEANUP */               
         MYABCODE = 100;                                           
         IF REASON = 51 THEN MYABCODE = 999;                       
         CALL CEE3ABD(MYABCODE,CLEANUP);                           
      END;                                                         
   END;                                                            
   ELSE DO;                                                        
      PUT SKIP LIST('NO ABEND');                                   
      RESULT = 20; /* PERCOLATE CONDITION */                       
   END;                                                            


END;
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem by using JNI call. Instead of relying on a user-written exit handler, I invoke the method Abend.abend directly from Java.

```
public class Abend {
    public static native void abend(int abcode, int reasoncode, int cleanup);
}
```

And C imlementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctest.h>
#include "Abend.h"

#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Abend_abend
  (JNIEnv * end, jclass class, jint code, jint reasoncode, jint timing) {
   /* fprintf(stderr, "values %d %d %d\n", code, reasoncode, timing);*/
   __cabend(code, reasoncode, timing);
}
```